# Stuck in "query end" status every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, profiler

I'm sick of seeing data in the slow query log, so I decided to check out what the fuss was all about.

An `UPDATE` query that is running up to tens of times per second is sometimes really slow. Here is the query:

```
UPDATE `user` SET
    `last_active` = NOW(), 
    `last_ip` = '<ip>' 
WHERE `name` = '<name>' 
LIMIT 1
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
  `last_active` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `last_active` (`last_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34003;
```

Usually the query takes ~0.2 ms, but every 5 minutes (accurately every 5 minutes, 10:00:12, 10:05:12, 10:10:12...) it takes over 250 ms, with all time spent with the status "query end".

Any idea what may be causing this? Why would one query run slow every 5 minutes? What is happening every 5 minutes that is affecting "query end"? No other processes are running.

MySQL version 5.5.44

Comment: Do you use any form of replication? I have seen everything freeze in "query end" in case of Galera master-master when the other node is locked (alter/slow processing etc). Another possibility might be IO - any backup running or something else which would run periodically each 5 minutes and used a lot of HW/IO capacity? (check cron logs, system events etc.)

Comment: No, no replication. It does look related to IO as kjournald's IO is spiking when this happens, but I have no idea why. I have disabled all other services and removed all cronjobs, but the spike is still there. I also  switched to MariaDB 10, and nothing changed. The only IO according to iotop is mysql and kjournald, but I'm not sure if that means that mysql is the one causing kjournald to spike.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75439/mysql-instance-stalling-doing-sync-index) similar question. Your situation might be somewhat different, but the question has the sorts of details (and links to more) that you'll need to figure out InnoDB write stall problems.

Comment: Could this be coinciding with log flushes?

Answer (score 1):

All uses of that table will run faster (some will run a lot faster) if you jettison `id` and make `name` the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Your `UPDATE` is currently looking in 2 BTrees, plus updating 2 BTrees.  The PK change would change those to 1 and 2.  More importantly it would simply the row locking.

How big is the table?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size?  innodb_io_read_threads?  What the heck, let's see `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, Please check innodb_buffer_pool_size configuration.

Increase your read io_thread and write_thread,which will help you to figure it out.