# MySql: Frequent crashes on server with substantial resources

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, crash

My MySQL server running the latest version of MySql on Ubuntu 16.x keeps crashing once or twice a day. Sometimes it repairs itself fairly quickly (10 minutes). Sometimes I have to reboot and do an fsck to get things running again.

What would be causing this?

Things I've tried so far:

- increased RAM from 1.5GB up to 5GB.
- Hardware Upgrades: MotherBoard, processor, RAM (DDR4) but that didn't help (it was running a 7 year old processor, now running 7th
  Gen Core I5).
- Setup UFW firewall to ensure it wasn't being caused by bots attacking MySQL or other services.
- In my.cnf, changed innodb_buffer_pool_size from 128MB to 500MB. *didn't help but still in place*
- I've run: mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases multiple times. *didn't help*
- In my.cnf, Decreased mysql max_connections from 151 to 80 and restarted mysql. *didn't help*
- Decreased apache MaxRequestWorkers from 150 to 100. *Didn't help. Still crashing.*
- I already had a 1GB Swap file. *Left it.*
- Scoured through Apache2 logs, SysLog, any other log that seemed appropriate but haven't found anything that caught my eye.
- Shutdown the server and tried to move the VM to another drive but it fails with File Error.
- My latest suspicion is this is being caused by a bad block but running badblocks seemed to trigger a crash at 25% complete. During the fsck I see this: fsck critical medium error, dev sda, sector 147306432

Here is a typical mysql error log:

> 2017-04-20T18:43:46.958430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 11791ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flu shed=92 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:44:11.989905Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6822ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=8 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:44:49.145162Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5021ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flus hed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:45:22.322429Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 26338ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flu shed=10 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:45:53.926808Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4510ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flus hed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:46:03.097400Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5384ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flus hed=13 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:46:39.247467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 14848ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flu shed=8 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:47:16.271672Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 29107ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flu shed=8 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:47:53.669557Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5969ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flus hed=37 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:50:23.879411Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 37671ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flu shed=6 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:55:07.190725Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000) 2017-04-20T18:55:07.235759Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
>   2017-04-20T18:55:10.486670Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_times tamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>   2017-04-20T18:55:11.563578Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) starting as process 24701 ...
>   2017-04-20T18:55:21.979225Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
>   2017-04-20T18:55:21.979250Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>   2017-04-20T18:55:21.979253Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2017-04-20T18:55:21.979256Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
>   2017-04-20T18:55:21.979259Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>   2017-04-20T18:55:21.979262Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO 2017-04-20T18:55:22.004800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>   2017-04-20T18:55:22.060762Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>   2017-04-20T18:55:22.104584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
>   2017-04-20T18:55:24.184701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   2017-04-20T18:55:24.210160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
>   2017-04-20T18:55:26.405242Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2017-04-20T18:55:27.508456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 35288448161
>   2017-04-20T18:55:27.508478Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 35288448170
>   2017-04-20T18:55:27.508630Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 35288448170
>   2017-04-20T18:55:27.508634Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>   2017-04-20T18:55:27.508637Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.516761Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.516785Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.516817Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.621736Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.622203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.622211Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.622565Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.672708Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.17 started; log sequence number 35288448170
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.672708Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 52462ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.673192Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.702959Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851553Z 0 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851568Z 0 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851574Z 0 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851575Z 0 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851578Z 0 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exits 2017-04-20T18:56:16.851579Z 0 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:16.851582Z 0 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists 2017-04-20T18:56:16.851583Z 0 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:17.044733Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
>   2017-04-20T18:56:17.044754Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
>   2017-04-20T18:56:17.044761Z 0 [Note] - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
>   2017-04-20T18:56:17.044779Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'. 2017-04-20T18:56:18.483575Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   2017-04-20T18:56:18.483706Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
>   2017-04-20T18:56:18.483716Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
>   2017-04-20T18:56:25.478293Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170420 13:56:25
>   2017-04-20T18:56:26.091240Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
>   2017-04-20T18:56:26.091423Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 (Ubuntu)
>   2017-04-20T18:56:26.155810Z 4 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './example/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
>   2017-04-20T18:56:26.155889Z 5 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './example/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
>   2017-04-20T18:56:26.156037Z 4 [Warning] Checking table:'./example/wp_options'
>   2017-04-20T18:56:35.816730Z 4 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './example/wp_usermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
>   2017-04-20T18:56:35.816875Z 4 [Warning] Checking table: './example/wp_usermeta'

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  For 3GB of RAM it needs to be about 1000M _if_ you are mostly using InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: Which Engine are you using?  It sounds like MyISAM, since I see "Checking table".

Comment: Mostly using InnoDB.

Comment: I've now installed MySQLTuner 1.6.0 and am following it's recommendations.

Comment: Still crashing despite tuning and larger innodb_buffer_pool_size. And I often have to reboot and do an fsck to get things running again.

Comment: `tried to move the VM to another drive but it fails with File Error` if you don't know how a red flag look like, that's how a red flag look like...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Shutdown the server and tried to move the VM to another drive but it
>     fails with File Error.
> - My latest suspicion is this is being caused by
>     a bad block but running badblocks seemed to trigger a crash at 25%
>     complete. During the fsck I see this: fsck critical medium error, dev
>     sda, sector 147306432

Don't waste your time on DB tuning & others things, your drive seem definitely guilty for me...

Try to make a dump of the DB with as much as you can, try a low level drive formatting and start a clean VM.

Comment: I agree that the main problem is most likely the drive. Further confirmation of this is another VM which has a disk on the same drive can, when certain files are hit, also trigger the datastore to get detached and not reattach until the physical machine is rebooted. But, I'd really like to find a way to move the VM to another drive and not rebuild it from scratch as that seems like it'd take 20 hours to get everything back to the way I have it.

Comment: @EfficionDave your don't seem to get the criticality of the situation: **you're about to loose the VM data's**. Make a backup, if it fail, try a byte-by-byte recovery mode copy of the virtual drive file, [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples) may help you a lot, but understand we already speak of days to get everything back from bad sectors.

Comment: For the last 3 days, I don't believe anything on the Ubuntu VM has triggered the drive to crash. It has been crashed by accessing certain files by a different VM. I've managed to move all the files for the other VMs off of the drive at this point so the Ubuntu VM is the only thing left on the drive and it has been very stable and the mysql logs are mostly quiet. I will definitely be getting rid of the drive but I'm still hopeful I can now move, backup, or repair the VM rather than rebuilding from scratch. I'll find out tonight.

Comment: @EfficionDave nice work so ;) Good luck with the copy, as already said, if the straight copy don't work, give a try with ddrescue, as it seem your drive is not totally dead, you have your chance to get back the few broken block...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may stem from an old issue with the page cleaner.

There are bug reports about it

- [InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 27876ms. The settings mig (5.7.11)](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81899)
- [Bug #76661 Improve help when reporting page cleaner loop taking too long (5.7.17, 8.0.1)](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76661)
- I mentioned some tuning to try for MySQL 5.6 in [MySQL instance stalling "doing SYNC index"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75439/mysql-instance-stalling-doing-sync-index/75496#75496)

What is interesting to note is someone actually narrowed down the page cleaner issue with regards to the InnoDB Buffer Pool instances. The post was written back in November 2016 ([MySQL InnoDB page_cleaner settings might not be optimal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121236/mysql-innodb-page-cleaner-settings-might-not-be-optimal/127805#127805)) That post mentions something from the MySQL 5.7 Documentation on [innodb_page_cleaners](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners). Here is the full first paragraph:

> The number of page cleaner threads that flush dirty pages from buffer pool instances. Page cleaner threads perform flush list and LRU flushing. A single page cleaner thread was introduced in MySQL 5.6 to offload buffer pool flushing work from the InnoDB master thread. In MySQL 5.7, InnoDB provides support for multiple page cleaner threads. A value of 1 maintains the pre-MySQL 5.7 configuration in which there is a single page cleaner thread. When there are multiple page cleaner threads, buffer pool flushing tasks for each buffer pool instance are dispatched to idle page cleaner threads. The innodb_page_cleaners default value was changed from 1 to 4 in MySQL 5.7. If the number of page cleaner threads exceeds the number of buffer pool instances, [innodb_page_cleaners](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners) is automatically set to the same value as [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances).

According to your question and its comments, your buffer pool may still be too small. Since the Buffer Pool is < 1G (1024M), [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) drops to 1. This, in turn, would force [innodb_page_cleaners](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners) to drop to 1.

You can verify than with

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_page_cleaners';
```

I would set the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) to 1536M (which is 1.5G). Then, upon mysqld restart, [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) would bounce up to its default of 8. Even though [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is dynamic, [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) is not. Therefore, you must set these values in `my.cnf` and restart mysqld (it is required).

Comment: I ran these statements:
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_page_cleaners';
And both were at 1 currently. I will try updating them once I've moved the VM to a new drive.